# SpringSecurity configure() method Configuration issues

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I've developed a REST api's where methods are secured with SpringSecurity.

**GITHUB LINK**-> [Project](https://github.com/stonethecoder/SpringSecurity-JPA-dbAuth)

It is working but not as expected

SpringSecurity.config
---------------------------

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailService).passwordEncoder(encode());


    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http
            .csrf().disable();
        http

            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/user/**")
            .authenticated()
            .anyRequest()
            .hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**")
            .authenticated()
            .anyRequest()
            .hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .permitAll();

        /*http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN")
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .permitAll();*/

    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encode() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

AdminController
----------------------

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder;

    @PostMapping("/add")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public String addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        String encodedPwd= encoder.encode(user.getPassword());
        user.setPassword(encodedPwd);
        userRepo.save(user);
        return "user added sucessfully...";
    }

    @GetMapping("/demo")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public String getDemo() {
        return "Hi";
    }

}
```

CustomController
-------------------------

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class CustomController {

    @GetMapping("/access")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('USER','ADMIN')")
    public String showUser() {

        return "Url Security Provided";
    }
}
```

CustomUserDetailService
-----------------------------

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user= userRepo.findByUsername(username);
        CustomUserDetails userDetails= null;

        if(user!= null) {
            userDetails= new CustomUserDetails();
            userDetails.setUser(user);
        }else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Found");
        }
        return userDetails;
    }

}
```

CustomUserDetail
-----------------

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private User user;


    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

        /*return user.getRoles().stream()
            .map(role->new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_"+ role))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());*/
        return user.getRoles().stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return user.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    public CustomUserDetails() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

User
----------

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="gen",strategy="increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
    private int user_id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    @OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL, fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="user_roles",
                    joinColumns= @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName= "user_id"), 
                    inverseJoinColumns= @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="role_id"))
    private Set<Roles> roles;

}
```

The problem is:
With the above setup I can access the URL which are for USER not for ADMIN
  If i'm commenting

```
http
            /*.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/user/**")
            .authenticated()
            .anyRequest()
            .hasRole("USER")
            .and()*/
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**")
            .authenticated()
            .anyRequest()
            .hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .permitAll();
```

Then I can access the **URL** which are for **ADMIN** but I'm missing authentication on **URL** which are for **USER**

Similarly If I'm commenting the **admin/** then **USER** part can be accessed. It behaving like Ordering which ever url is in  first it is recognizing that and the second one is simply giving 403 in browser not anything in console.

It is something like Order which is first that can be accessed

Is there anywhere I'm doing wrong.

If I do not comment `@EnableGlobalSecurity`, `@PreAuthorize`, I can't access any of the **URL** those are for **ADMIN** and **USER** simply `403`, so I cant miss `@EnableGlobalSecurity`, `@PreAuthorize` as these are for Securing REST API Methods

Comment: changing it to `.antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
 .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("USER")` should help. you do not need to call `authorizeRequests` multiple times

Comment: I have tried it already in this case neither I can access the USER based URL nor ADMIN based URL

Comment: Even if in console DB queries are getting fired but simply 403 in browser

Comment: It's SPRING JPA so in userRepo i have one method which loads the user according to the given username

Comment: While you say,  sql queries are being executed it means the method is getting executed (and you can place debug pointer and debug the method for confirmation), however it is returning 403 means, at high level, something is failing with `@Postauthorize` but we do not see any method annotated with the same either `@Preauthorize` is commented as per your posted code and hence not concerning with `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`. can you share the logs?

Comment: How does the mapping for user to role looks like in database?

Comment: Check now I'have updated the question enabled @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled= true), @PreAuthorize and etc

Answer (score 0):

Just add permission to all your pages for your admin role. This way you make sure that your admin can access any page he wants.

```
http
            /*.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/user/**")
            .authenticated()
            .anyRequest()
            .hasRole("USER")
            .and()*/
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**")
            .hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/user/**")
            .hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .permitAll();
```